# upload hyperlink data to azure binding

Tags: python, json, azure

I am trying to stream data from hyperlink destination to azure storage. I have to do this via binding since I want to run this from azure function App.

file -- function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{rand-guid}",
      "connection": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

file -- **init.py**:

```
import logging
import cdsapi
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, outputBlob:func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function is about to process request.')

    try:
        source_blob="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
        with open(source_blob, "rb") as data:
            print(data)
            outputBlob.set(data)
    except Exception as ex:
        logging.info("  error!", ex, "occurred.")
    return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
                status_code=200
            )
```

I have tested binding and it works. When I simply do `outputBlob.set("sample string")` data is streamed as it should be.
I am stuck with converting data from hyperlink to bytes(or blob). While running code above, i get error `Exception: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`. Any help in converting this and uploading to azure storage is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you were trying to read the File from URL `with open(source_blob, "rb") as data:` which of course won't work since `open` is for local files only. I have changed your code as below using `requests` module to get the remote URL response and set the content to blob.

```
import requests

source_url="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf"
with requests.get(source_url, stream=True) as r:
    r.raise_for_status()
    outputBlob.set(r.content)
```